# Database event listener using spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

I need to attach a listener to a table in db
which should call a spring boot method, once CRUD operation is performed in the table(pre listeners and post listeners)
the entry can be made from any source
how can i do that in spring boot?

Comment: I don't think spring boot is going to give you that power.  You can get get such behavior out of your JPA entities.  You need to look in a different place!

Answer (score 3):

If the entity can be created from any source - e.g. manual insert - this is something which is outside of the scope and context of your running application.

What you're describing is known as the [CDC (change data capture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture) pattern.

To implement CDC in this case you need to use the instrumentation of the underlying database - for example triggers.

As I see this is tagged with MongoDb - triggers are not an option as mongodb doesn't have support for triggers.

If you are using MongoDb v3.6+ you can leverage the new [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/changeStreams/) feature. This is the [official example](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver-async/tutorials/change-streams/) with Java.

> [Change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) allow applications to access real-time data changes
> without the complexity and risk of tailing the [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/). Applications can
> use change streams to subscribe to all data changes on a single
> collection, a database, or an entire deployment, and immediately react
> to them. Because change streams use the aggregation framework,
> applications can also filter for specific changes or transform the
> notifications at will.

If you are using earlier versions of MongoDb you can monitor the [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) or use [tailable cursors](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.tailable/) with capped collections.

Another approach would be to look into a 3rd party solution that turns everything happening in the DB as event streams - like for example [debezium](https://debezium.io/).

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39522/execution-of-a-java-program-by-a-trigger) explains how to call any program from DB-Trigger.

Therefore, you can just create a Spring Boot java app and make the sys call to your app.

Similar mechanism is also available in Oracle and other DB.